# Message: Undefined variable in controller of codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, undefined

I am using codeigniter for getting country city dynamically but i get the following

**error: Message: Undefined variable: country_id
        Filename: controllers/countries.php**

My Controller is:

```
class countries extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Countries_model');
}
public function country()
{
    $data=array();
    $this->load->database();
    $data['countries']=$this->Countries_model->get_countries();
    $this->load->view('countries_view',$data);
}   
public function get_cities()
{
    $this->load->model('Countries_model');
$cities = $this->Countries_model->get_cities_by_country_id($country_id);

echo json_encode($cities);

}
```

View:

```
<select id="country" name="country">
<option value="0">Select Country</option>
<?php   foreach($countries as $val)
{
echo '<option   value="'.$val['pkCountry'].'">'.$val['CountryName'].'</option>';

}
?>
</select>

<select id="city" name="city">
<option value="0">Select City</option>
</select>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#country").change(function(e) {
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  $.getJSON("/countries/get_cities/" + selectedVal, {}, function(cities) {
    if(cities) {
      $("#city").html("<option value=" + MCity.pkMCity + ">"+ MCity.Name +"</option>"); 
    }
  });
});
});
</script>
```

Model:

```
public function get_cities_by_country_id($country_id) {
$this->db->where('fkMCountry', $country_id);
$query = $this->db->get('MCity');

return $query->result();
}
```

Route:

```
$route['countries/get_cities'] = 'countries/get_cities';
```

Database tables
Country:

pkCountry  CountryName

City:

fkMCountry  Name

Answer (score 0):

### First - controller

Your controller should have classname with the first letter uppercase

change:

```
class countries extends CI_Controller {
```

to:

```
class Countries extends CI_Controller {
```

Furthermore in your code, inside the function

```
public function get_cities()
{
    $this->load->model('Countries_model');
$cities = $this->Countries_model->get_cities_by_country_id($country_id);

echo json_encode($cities);

}
```

you refer to the parameter $country_id which is not passed to that function. This is why you get the error. Try the below, should eliminate the error.

```
public function get_cities($country_id)
    {
        $this->load->model('Countries_model');
    $cities = $this->Countries_model->get_cities_by_country_id($country_id);

    echo json_encode($cities);

    }
```

### Second - javascript

you have a spelling issue in your javascript code which is causing the second error (you provided in comments)

change:

```
var selectedValue = $(this).val();
$.getJSON("/countries/get_cities/" + selectedVal, {}, function(cities)
```

to:

```
var selectedValue = $(this).val();
$.getJSON("countries/get_cities/" + selectedValue, {}, function(cities)
```

### Third - routing

Your route definition does not indicate that there will be a third segment in the uri (symbolysing your $country_id parameter passed to function). Use the below and it should finally work.

```
$route['countries/get_cities/(:num)'] = 'countries/get_cities/$1';
```

or if you still have problems, try

```
$route['countries/get_cities/(:any)'] = 'countries/get_cities/$1';
```

Comment: I get an error:
Message: Missing argument 1 for countries::get_cities()
Filename: controllers/countries.php
@Gadoma

Comment: can you provide the full code of the conroller, not just the function get_cities ?

Comment: No @Gadoma...The country dropdown is displayed but still have a problem with onchange to get the cities...

Comment: what are the errors you get? point your browser to that url you are fetching with json and paste the output (echo json_encode($cities);) in your post

Comment: @user3114651 you should accept and +1 the answer as it solved you original problems (the initial CI related question)

Comment: My problem is still not solved @Gadoma .... I still get the same errors :
Message: Missing argument 1 for countries::get_cities()
Filename: controllers/countries.php
Line Number: 36
    &
Message: Undefined variable: country_id
Filename: controllers/countries.php
Line Number: 39

The country value is fetched fine but it does not take the onchange event after that